# What does `exec 200>lockfile` do?

Tags: bash, exec

I'm not familiar with the `exec` command. A bash tutorial about how to lock files throws this:

```
exec 200>lockfile 
flock 200
...
flock -u 200
```

I got that it is creating a file named `lockfile` and assigning it an FD of 200. Then the second command locks that file. When done working with the file, the last command unlocks it.

Doing so, any other concurrent instance of the same script will stay at that second line until the first instance unlocks the file. Cool.

Now, what I don't understand is what is `exec` doing.

Directly from the bash command line, both options seem to work:

```
exec 200>lockfile
200>lockfile
```

But when the second option is used in the script, a "Bad file descriptor error" is raised.

Why is `exec` needed to avoid the error?

--- edit ---

After some more "serious research", I've found an answer [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html). The `exec` command makes the FD stay for the entire script or current shell.

So doing:

```
200>lockfile flock 200
```

Would work. But later `flock -u 200` would raise a "Bad FD error".

Comment: The manual also says *If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell*. What are you asking here?

Comment: @oguzismail was that an attempt of an answer? it didn't help. if you're the downvoter, I'd appreciate to know why so I can improve the question...

Comment: It was an uncouth comment. Yes, I am, and I downvoted because this question doesn't show any sign of serious research.

Comment: Found a good answer here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The manual seems to mention shell replacement with given command. What does that has to do with file descriptors?

This is explained in the second sentence:

```
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
    Exec FILE, replacing this shell with the specified program.
    If FILE is not specified, the redirections take effect in this
    shell. [...]
```

Essentially, doing `exec 42> foo.txt` from inside `myscript.sh` opens `foo.txt` for writing on FD 42 in the current process.

This is similar to running `./myscript.sh 42> foo.txt` from a shell in the first place, or using `open` and `dup2` in a C program.